# How to conver float to sizeF?

Tags: c#

I have a panel where i am wring an string to a rectangle by default i have set the width of panel 300 that i am setting to a variable of type float, and i wring some string to it, but i want to identify that next item being drawn can be adapted to remaining space or i need to start it from new row i am calculating the remaining space like below.
But it can not cast float to sizeF.

```
foreach (btnObject custItem in this.lstAcceptedCustomizatio)
{
    System.Drawing.SizeF newString = g.MeasureString(custItem.BtnName + ", ", this.Font); //get the size of the text property
    System.Drawing.SizeF drawnString = g.MeasureString(basketItemDescription, this.Font); //get the size of the text property
    if(newString.Width> (this.Width-drawnString)) //THIS LINE DO NOT WORK
        basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + custItem.BtnName + ", ";
}
```

Comment: This? `this.Width-drawnString.Width`. Also, is `btnObject` a type?

Comment: yes, here the width is panel width that i set from property window for panel, that i set to a property of type flot and performing operaion.

Comment: i want to know whether i can draw the next item to remaining space of the width after wring an item or i should start the whole item from next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls are using integer values internally and the size and locations cannot be set to float numbers.

```
SizeF has a ToSize method

Size size = sizeF.ToSize();

or

myControl.Size = sizeF.ToSize();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(newString.Width> this.Width-drawnString.Width) ....
```